# Implement Material image loading pattern using css filters

Tags: css, material-design

Material design guidelines provide an [image loading pattern](https://material.io/archive/guidelines/patterns/loading-images.html).

[image]

Since there is quite a lot of people following these guidelines, I was wondering if an implementation of it exists in css? It seems that using [css filters](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/) with filters transtitions, it could be possible but I am not sure that it can be animated as described by the guidelines.

Note that I know there is [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27262022/how-to-implement-loading-images-pattern-opacity-exposure-and-saturation-fro) but it is for native android development (Java).

To sum it up, can it be done and if so, has it be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `gamma()` for CSS filters yet, but you can try using `brightness()`. It is not the same thing, however, but perhaps close enough for a cigar?

In the example below I am using the `cubic-bezier(0.7,0,0.6,1)` timing function as an [approximation of Google Material Design](http://sprawledoctopus.com/easing/)'s "Heavy Move" easing function, but you can use any other cubic bezier curve definition to better approximate the timing function shown in Googles' MD chart. Here is the proof-of-concept example, with [vendor prefixes added by JS](https://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/).

*Note:* If the animation looks off, that's because the images not loaded before the animation runs. Re-run the code snippet if that's the case

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.images {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.images img {
  /* Animation */
  animation: material-design__image 3s;
  animation-fill-mode: forward;

  /* Layout only */
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  width: calc(50vw - 2rem);
}

/* Approximation of Material Design specifications */
@keyframes material-design__image {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    filter: saturate(20%) brightness(125%);
  }
  66.7% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  83.3% {
    filter: saturate(87%) brightness(100%);
  }
  100% {
    filter: saturate(100%) brightness(100%);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class="images">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/5nDXHEZ.jpg" alt="" title="" />
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/hQNpUeA.jpg" alt="" title="" />
</div>
```

A little explanation of the keyframe definition:

- Percentage stops are decided based on the Google MD chart you have provided. For a total duration of 3s, `66.7%` corresponds to around the 2s timepoint, and `83.3%` to the 2.5s timepoint.
- Since filters cannot be stacked, we will have to manually compute the value of saturation (at 83.3% timepoint—if we do not declare the saturation, it will be reset to 100%). This value depends on the cubic-bezier curve you're using. For the curve that I am using in the code snippet, the value shoud be around `87%` at 83.3%. This is a pure approximation, and inferred from [here](http://cubic-bezier.com/#.6,0,.7,1).

Comment: Very nice! I plan to use it in conjunction with an image lazy loading component, so the image should be preloaded. Hats off you sir! :-)

Comment: @Billybobbonnet Thanks for the upvote and the accept! I have included some explanation of the keyframe animation, and further information on how I arrived at the saturation value at 83.3% timepoint :)